# Join multiple table return no results

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I have SQL query joining multiple tables.

```sql
SELECT a.fourbnumber,a.fourbdate,a.taxcollector,b.cashcheque,c.propertycode
from tbl_rphead a
inner join tbl_rpdetail b on a.rpid = b.rpid
inner join tbl_assessmregister c on b.assessmid = c.assessmid
```

I can execute that query in Sql Editor with fast manner (3 secs). When I execute that query using JAVA(JDBC), it doesn’t returns any results and no exceptions
I don’t know how to fix that problem.

Each table has 200k records

Comment: Your Java program obviously opens a different database file.

Comment: when I try to join two tables, Its returns correct results sets

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: @Maniraj try this, `SELECT a.fourbnumber,a.fourbdate,a.taxcollector,b.cashcheque,c.propertycode
from tbl_rphead a
left join tbl_rpdetail b on a.rpid = b.rpid
left join tbl_assessmregister c on b.assessmid = c.assessmid`

Answer (score 1):

Your Sql Editor might limiting the result to some count to show the records in view. See the editor you may find the hint showing 500 of XXXXXX

When you calling it from JDBC it may get the results faster from DB, but it need to fill up the result set objects for those lacs of records. It will more time and memory.

If you are working with `oracle DB` try limiting records in your query with help of `rownum < 100` , so you could get the results in java/jdbc. `If it works go with SQL pagination technique with rownum < x and rownum > y`

Comment: Thanks your reply, In SQL Lite tool editor, I will get only 1 to 5 records as results thats correct for my required... But In JDBC connection I could not get anything....

Comment: When I try with Java Main application, I can get the Results.. In Web application I could not get

Comment: So, you mean the join query result have only 5 records and the same is not getting fetched in JDBC code. So, can you pls past the Error stack which you getting in webApplication ?